# Angular 2 Classes, and large json file

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Currently the system I'm interacting with to request JSON essentially returns me a batch file that contains LARGE amounts of data. Trying to follow the spec of the Angular 2 (Heros) tutorial in relation to defining a class and then defining every property that will be returned seems almost impossible in my case.

I'm trying to find a solution on how to handle this because I don't think this is the right way to handle it:

```js
export class Example {
  prop1: number,
  prop2: string,
  prop3: {
    prop : string,
    prop : string,
    prop : string,
    prop : string,
    prop : string,
    prop : [{
      prop : string,
      prop : string,
      prop : string,
      prop : string,
      prop : string,
    }];
  },
  prop : string,
  prop : string,
  prop3: {
    prop : string,
    prop : string,
    prop : string,
    prop : string,
    prop : string,
    prop : [{
      prop : string,
      prop : string,
      prop : string,
      prop : string,
      prop : [{
        prop : string,
        prop : string,
        prop : string,
        prop : string,
        prop : string,
    }];,
    }];
  },
}
```

Or is the best way to actually request the JSON Data, THEN parse it into particular classes? Or something better I'm not even thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interface to represent the json that you receive.

You can be explicit and declare each property:

```
interface Prop3 {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
    prop3: string;
    prop4: string;
    prop5: string;
    prop6: Prop3[];
}

interface Example {
    prop1: number;
    prop2: string;
    prop3: Prop3;
}
```

You can also use [indexable interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types):

```
interface Example {
    prop1: number;
    prop2: string;
    prop3: { [key: string]: string };
}
```

The problem with the indexable approach is that the compiler won't be able to tell you if you used the right property name.

---

#### Edit

If you're not explicit and use an indexed interface then the compiler can't know which keys are right and which are wrong.
For example let's say I receive a json data object from the server which contains the following strings: firstName, lastName, username.

If the interface is:

```
interface Data {
    [key: string]: string;
}

let data: Data; // from server
console.log(data["firstName"]);
console.log(data["firstname"]); // ok but shouldn't be 
console.log(data["dontExists"]); // also ok but shouldn't
```

On the other hand:

```
interface Data {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    username: string;
}

let data: Data; // from server
console.log(data.firstName);
console.log(data.firstname); // error: Property 'firstname' does not exist on type 'Data'
console.log(data.dontExists); // error: Property 'dontExists' does not exist on type 'Data'
```

Comment: In relation to being explicit, just to clarify I would still need to write (in my case) 1000x lines to define what's coming back still right?

Comment: Indeed.  Check my revised answer. You'll need to ask yourself if you prefer to write (or maybe automate?) this interface(s) and get type safety or you prefer not to.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it really does help me better understand how to handle this. In relation to automating the interfaces, do you suggest some basic logic that says... If(objects in object) then Interface X,Y,Z? Type of thing?

Comment: No, I meant use an automated tool to make it for you, I've never used any, but you can try this one: http://json2ts.com/ or search for more.

Comment: If I could upvote your comment 5000 times I would. Thanks for the tip Nitzan!